# My car will not start after being driven fine

Tags: starting, gmc, envoy

I have a 2003 gmc envoy xl it has been running fine..drove it all day. Went home 4 hrs later it will not start.. It acts like it is dead but everything from the lights to the heat works fine..I mean it doesn't make a noise no nothing..it has a new alternator and new battery.. But if it's my starter shouldn't I hear a noise?

Comment: If the battery is ok it's possibly an immobiliser issue, are you using the same keys? Try pressing the unlock button a couple of times if it has remote locking. Also (sorry if this is obvious) check that the gear selector is in park.

Comment: Along the lines of what Sam was saying, but is there a security light lit on the dash?

Comment: Hi sam .. yes its in park..but i have been having problems with with the remote locking sometimes it unlocks sometimes it doesnt. but i only have one key. i just read that it could prevent the car from starting so how do i check it or fix it at this point

Comment: Paulster ..yes there is a security light on that the dash..

Answer (score 3):

> But if it's my starter shouldn't I hear a noise

Not if the starter solenoid is stuck. This is the piece of metal that connects the circuit and allows the starter motor to receive power. It's usually pulled into place magnetically, thereby connecting two terminals and powering the motor. When solenoids age, they tend to stick, or, in some cases, physically break. Once the bridge no longer works, no power can get to the motor.

[image]

To test it, you can temporarily realign the solenoid by hitting it with a hammer a few times and see if it starts after that. Disclaimer: Don't go around hitting random parts of your car with a hammer, if you aren't sure which one is the starter.

If the hammer trick does resolve the issue, it's likely only a temporary fix. Once a solenoid begins to act like this, it's probably going to give a repeat performance sometime in the future. If it sounds like I learned this lesson the hard way, well... yeah. Just assume that this may be the last time the car starts with this solenoid.

One last note: Sometimes solenoids are attached and sold as one piece with the starter, other times they are separate. My Jeep is one piece; my lawn tractor is separate.